# Does a default virtual destructor prevent compiler-generated move operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, virtual-destructor

Inspired by the post *[Why does destructor disable generation of implicit move methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932824/why-destructor-disabling-the-generation-of-implicit-move-functions)*, I was wondering if the same is true for the default virtual destructor, e.g.

```
class WidgetBase // Base class of all widgets
{
    public:
        virtual ~WidgetBase() = default;
        // ...
};
```

As the class is intended to be a base class of a widget hierarchy I have to define its destructor virtual to avoid memory leaks and undefined behavior when working with base class pointers. On the other hand I don't want to prevent the compiler from automatically generating move operations.

Does a default virtual destructor prevent compiler-generated move operations?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, declaring any destructor will prevent the implicit-declaration of the move constructor.

> `N3337 [class.copy]/9:` If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>
> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - **X does not have a user-declared destructor**, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

Declaring the destructor and defining it as `default` counts as *user-declared*.

You'll need to declare the move constructor and define it as `default` yourself:

```
WidgetBase(WidgetBase&&) = default;
```

Note that this will in turn define the copy constructor as `delete`, so you'll need to `default` that one too:

```
WidgetBase(const WidgetBase&) = default;
```

The rules for copy and move assignment operators are pretty similar as well, so you'll have to `default` them if you want them.

Comment: Apparently a user-defined virtual destructor would not delete the move operations. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b95b6bb23630755f

Comment: @dwto I think compilers are not implementing this rule?

Comment: actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901837/how-to-get-if-a-type-is-truly-move-constructible

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution, but one of possible workarounds.
You can inherit all of your classes from a class that has only default virtual destructor.

I checked using GCC 9 and Apple's Clang++ with `-std=c++17`: both of them generate move constructors for classes that inherit the class below.

```cpp
class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;
};
```

The class below will indeed have a move constructor.

```cpp
class Child : public Object {
public:
    Child(std::string data) : data(data) {
    }

private:
    std::string data;

};
```

Another possible but risky workaround would be to not declare virtual destructors at all. It would introduce the following risks:

- All objects must always be destructed by someone who knows their exact type. Which is not really that big of a problem in a nicely designed C++ code.
- When object of such class is stored in a container like `std::vector` or `std::list` it must always be wrapped using `std::shared_ptr`. `std::unique_ptr` would cause leaks! That's related to their differences related to storing deleter.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out your first suggestion for a while.... So I think it says: the base class will not get a move c'tor, but the derived class will (because it does not have a virtual d'tor of its own)? - thanks for confirming :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and isn't really useful information