# Is it good practice to write constructor/destructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

I wonder if it's a good practice to always write constructor/destructor even if I don't use them.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){};
    ~Foo(){};
};
```

Or is it a better practice to write them only when I actually use them?

```
class Foo
{
public:
};
```

Comment: Note that declaring a virtual destructor will force each object of your class to contain a vtable-pointer, increasing its memory usage by one word (e.g. 8 bytes) per `Foo` that is created.  So if you know that your `Foo` class will never use virtual methods (and/or will never be inherited by a subclass that uses virtual methods), then there is an advantage to not declaring a virtual destructor (declaring a non-virtual destructor would not increase memory usage though).  OTOH if you know the object will be using virtual methods, then declaring a virtual destructor is a good idea.

Comment: no reason writing constructor, and in particular `vritual` destructor in this case. Please think of some more real-life example.

Comment: "use them" seems to have a very different meaning to you than the way C++ is discussed by experts (and in the Standard).  In common parlance, "using" a function (including a special member function) happens if you call it or take its address.  You seem to mean when you write something in the function body.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't for questions of opinion.

Comment: @xaxxon There are differences between "primarily opinion-based question" and "question whose answer will contain some opinions". "Primarily" is the keyword.

Comment: @NickyC whether you should **always** do it, is going to be primarily opinion and that's what the question asks.

Comment: @xaxxon But the question isn't *asking* for opinions, and the OP may not realize that it's a matter of opinion. A reasonable answer here could be "That's a matter of opinion; some people do it because ___, while others think it's unnecessary because ___." A lot of good and valid questions are like this. The aim of the guideline is to stop questions from turning into debates.

Comment: @caleb The question asks for "better practice" without qualifying it.   That's an opinion.

Comment: @xaxxon: It's not an open-ended request for the best practice, it presents exactly two options and asks which *of those two* is better.  A question that has fact-based answers.  Just because you thought of an opinion-based answer does not make all other answers, or the question itself, opinion-based.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bad idea to user-define special member functions when the default ones are sufficient.

- You will lose the default-generated move operations, see [Does a default virtual destructor prevent compiler-generated move operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33957037/103167)
- Your class will no longer be trivial, causing allocation and deallocation and containers holding your class to become much less efficient.
- The defaulted definitions may be automatically `noexcept`, but you lost that.
- Your class is no longer an aggregate, so you can't use aggregate initialization.
- If you make the destructor virtual, as shown in your question, you also lose standard-layout.

Comment: Also, depending on the ABI trivially copyable type can be passed to function more efficiently (passed in a register rather than on the stack).

Comment: It is not. I am not talking about the c++ language specification but calling conventions as described for exemple in the itanium c++ ABI.

Comment: @Oliv: The rules of the specification restrict the calling conventions.  A variable can live in a register and have no memory address only if both the specification and the ABI permit it.