# rule of zero vs. base class destructors

Tags: c++, c++11, rule-of-zero

I have a base class `Base` and a derived class `D`, and I'd like to have move constructor and move assignment operator automatically generated by the compiler for me. Following the [Rule of Zero](http://blog.florianwolters.de/educational/2015/01/31/The_Rule_of_Zero/), I leave all memory management to the compiler and only use level-2 classes (no raw pointers, arrays, etc.):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    Base(): a_(42) {}
    virtual void show() { std::cout << "Base " << a_ << std::endl; }

  private:
    int a_;
};

class D : Base {
  public:
    D(): b_(666) {}
    void show() { std::cout << "D " << b_ << std::endl; }

  private:
    int b_;
};

int main() {
  Base b;
  b.show();
  D d;
  d.show();
  return 0;
}
```

This should be it, right?

Enter [the C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#a-namerc-dtor-virtualac35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-nonvirtual):

> A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual.

Ah, so I guess I'll have to add a destructor to `Base`. But that'll do away with the automatically generated move functions!

What's the clean way out here?

Comment: You can `= default` the destructor, and declare it public virtual or protected, as you see fit.

Comment: Strongly related: [Why does destructor disable generation of implicit move methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33932824/514235)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `= default` everything that you would like to be generated by the compiler.
See (at the bottom): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

In your case it could look something like:

```
class Base{
  public:
    Base(): a_(42) {}
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void show() { std::cout << "Base " << a_ << std::endl; }

  private:
    int a_;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create once a class like

```
struct VirtualBase
{
      virtual ~VirtualBase() = default;
      VirtualBase() = default;
      VirtualBase(const VirtualBase&) = default;
      VirtualBase(VirtualBase&&) = default;
      VirtualBase& operator = (const VirtualBase&) = default;
      VirtualBase& operator = (VirtualBase&&) = default;
};
```

And then follow rule of zero:

```
class Base : VirtualBase
{
public:
    Base(): a_(42) {}
    virtual void show() { std::cout << "Base " << a_ << std::endl; }

  private:
    int a_;
};
```

Comment: Nice suggestion & I was about to write this answer. But wasn't sure, what will be its fate when there is multiple inheritance involved. Isn't it safe to inherit `VirtualBase` virtually?

Comment: @iammilind: virtual inheritance has a higher cost than simple inheritance, so unless needed, I will stick with normal inheritance.

Comment: @iammilind it is safe to inherit either virtually or not.