# vector becomes empty when the operator() is executed by std::thread

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdthread

I’m trying to create a thread (PrinStringManager) which in turn creates several threads (PrintEntry) (depending on the number of elements of the incoming vector of strings).
Each PrintEntry thread created simply prints the string received in the constructor.

It is just a small example representing my problem.

```
class PrintEntry
{
public:
    PrintEntry(std::string& name) :name_(name) {}
    ~PrintEntry() {}
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "name: " << name_;
    }
private:

    std::string name_;
};

class PrinStringManager
{
public:
    PrinStringManager(std::vector<std::string>& vec) :vec_(vec){}
    ~PrinStringManager() {
        for (auto& t : vt_) t.join();
    }

    void operator()() {
        for (auto name : vec_)
        {
            vt_.emplace_back(PrintEntry{ name });
        }
    }

private:

    std::vector<std::string> vec_;
    std::vector<std::thread> vt_;
};


void f()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "one","two", "three" };
    PrinStringManager psm{ vec };
    std::thread t{ std::ref(psm) };
    t.detach();
} 

int main()
{
    f();
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

What it is happening, is that the object PrinStringManager is created with a vector of 3 strings but when the object function (from PrintStringmanager) is invokek by the thread, the vector is empty:

```
void operator()() {
    for (auto name : vec_) //<-- vec is empty!!
    {
        vt_.emplace_back(PrintEntry{ name });
    }
}
```

I noticed that when the end of scope for function f() is reached the destructor of PrinStringManager is called and that should be the problem.

Is there a way to o overcome this problem in a simply manner without setting PrinStringManager as static so that it lives forever?

Is there a way to move psm inside the thread object so that when the end of scope of f() is reached, the psm inside the thread hold the original value?

Comment: Yes, create the `PrintStringManager` in `main` and pass a reference to it to `f`.

Comment: "I noticed that when the end of scope for function f() is reached the destructor of `PrinStringManager` is called and that should be the problem." No not really, because the `PrinStringManager` destructor will not return until all the threads created by the manager have been joined.

Comment: What *is* a problem is that you pass a reference to the local `psm` object to your detached thread. First it's a problem because the threads created by `psm` might have ended before `t` even starts. But it's a bigger problem that the life-time of `pfm` could end before the thread `t` finishes, and leave you with an invalid reference.

Comment: @Some programmer dude 
So, should i use static PrinStringManager psm; instead?

Comment: this is the problem with using `thread.detach()` it makes it much easier to mishandle object lifetimes. You're storing a reference to the local variable `vec` which ceases to exist at the end of `f()`, `psm` is also a local variable so storing the reference to that doesn't work either

Comment: @AlanBirtles But the vector of string is copied inside PrintStringManager! And psm will cease to exist....

Comment: ah, ok, if its copied then why is it passed by lvalue reference rather than const reference or r-value reference

Comment: @AlanBirtles you mean pass psm as r-value to the thread?

Comment: no, passing the vector into psm by l-value is confusing, conventionally it would be a const l-value or r-value. It won't fix anything but it makes your code clearer

Comment: @AlanBirtles is there a way to move psm inside the thread object so that when the end of scope of f() is reached, the psm inside the thread hold the original value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make your object movable by adding a move constructor:

```cpp
    // No implicitly declared one since you have a destructor, so bring it back
    PrinStringManager(PrinStringManager&&) = default;
    // Also the move assign is probably wanted
    PrinStringManager& operator=(PrinStringManager&&) = default;

// (And also fix `PrintEntry`, probably by removing the destructor)
```

Then you can make the thread hold its own `PrinStringManager` object, instead of merely a reference to one on the stack:

```cpp
// The thread will hold a PrinStringManager move-constructed from psm
std::thread t{ std::move(psm) };
```

---

If you can't make `PrinStringManager` movable for whatever reason, you can use dynamic allocation:

```cpp
void f()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "one","two", "three" };
    auto psm = std::make_unique<PrinStringManager>(vec);
    // The thread holds a pointer to `psm` which is deleted
    // when the thread finishes
    std::thread t{ [psm=std::move(psm)]{ (*psm)(); } };
    t.detach();
}
```

Comment: Already tried that but the compiler complains with:
`error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: @eniac Turns out your class wasn't movable (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33932824 for more information, and follow the rule of 0/3/5)

Comment: Yes, i can make it moveable. Fixed already. Thanks.